# how to change vscode tooltip pop up style into block style?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using window machine how can one set this tooltip style?

[image: vscode tooltip]

This is my current tooltip style.

[image: current vscode tooltip]

Comment: what if you click the `Peek Problem` link

Comment: exactly! it worked!